# Cassandra cluster automation using ansible playbook in azure

Tags: azure, ansible, cassandra

I am a new joinee in an org. and a task has been assigned to me to automate cassandra cluster using ansible playbook in azure environment. So far I've not found any usefull documentation on this so can anyone help me because DSA sure isn't helpful here.

I've tried manually setting up cassandra on azure now i want to automate that using playbook.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems. Asking open-ended, subjective questions is frowned upon here so I recommend spending some time on [learning how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what types of questions to avoid](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) so you have a better chance of getting help. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I spent less than a minute of searching on the internet and found the following resources:

- Blog - [Setting Up Cassandra Cluster Through Ansible](https://medium.com/knoldus/setting-up-cassandra-cluster-through-ansible-59da14358313)
- Blog - [Installing Cassandra and Spark with Ansible](https://batey.info/installing-cassandra-and-spark-with.html)
- GitHub - [ansible-collections/community.cassandra](https://github.com/ansible-collections/community.cassandra)

If you spend a few more minutes than I did, I'm sure you'd come up with more. Cheers!